# multiple firewalls with symfony2

Tags: security, symfony

How to have multiple firewalls with symfony2?

This is mentioned in the documentation but never explained.

Comment: this is my current progress : http://pastebin.com/3ke7FgLj
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Here is the final working security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        entity_admin:
            class: MyBundle\Entity\AdminUser
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 5000
            encode_as_base64: false
        entity_members:
            class: MyBundle\Entity\User
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 1000
            encode_as_base64: false

    providers:
        entity_admin:
            entity:
                class: MyBundle\Entity\AdminUser
                property: username
        entity_members:
            entity:
                class: MyBundle\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        admin_secured_area:
            pattern: /admin/.*
            provider: entity_admin
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                login_path: /admin/login
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin/
        members_secured_area:
            pattern: /members/.*
            provider: entity_members
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /members/login_check
                login_path: /members/login
            logout:
                path:   /members/logout
                target: /members/

    access_control:
        admin_login:
            path: /admin/login
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        admin_area:
            path: /admin/.*
            roles: ROLE_ADMIN
        members_login:
            path: /members/login
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        members_register:
            path: /members/register
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        members_area:
            path: /members/.*
            roles: ROLE_USER
```

And a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aC7GaZKW)

Comment: Did you manage to make it work with this solution ? When I try to reach the login_check url, I have the error explained here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html#be-sure-login-check-is-behind-a-firewall

Answer (score 4):

In your yml config file put:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        filrewall_1:
            ...
        filrewall_2:
            ...
```

Post a comment if you have problems.

See also : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

Comment: the problem is that i need different encoders, providers...
here is what i've tried, i think i'm completely wrong...
http://pastebin.com/1t8w9NtT

Comment: Yes it's messy :) if you want 2 firewalls don't duplicate all the configuration, just put another firewall config  under `security.firewalls`. I've tried to clean up your config file a little bit, i haven't tested it but it's a good start: http://pastebin.com/hzGjCJe3. Another thing i see i that you should rename you provider from `main` to `secured_area` or providing a `provider_name` (with 'main' value)  under your `secured_area` firewall

Comment: with this kind of config, i don't understand how can i have 2 different entities with different algorithms, differents secured areas...

Comment: let say you have two entites `User` and `Account`, look at this: http://pastebin.com/5nS0x7bc

Comment: I think we are close, I have this error :
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "entity_user, entity_account" under "security.providers.main"

Comment: all is indicated in the link i send you (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html), just check it, the error you have is easily understandable.

Comment: I'm nearest : http://pastebin.com/3ke7FgLj
I ended up with this error : ServiceNotFoundException: The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.user.provider.concrete.entity_admin".

Comment: as indicated in the error message, your service "security.user.provider.concrete.entity_admin" (wich should be a user provider) does not exists, i think it's indicated in the doc.

Comment: i'm sorry i really don't understand, if you're refering about how to create an user provider, the doc is incomplete http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html
also when i was working with one provider, i didn't need this...
so i don't understand

Comment: you don't need to create one if you use ORM take this one : security.user.provider.entity, look here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security.xml

Comment: ok thanks, then i don't understand, how to link each firewall with its own entity/encoder

Comment: What does that mean ? It's not the firewall who is linked to an encoder but the user. your encoder is linked to entites, which are linked to user providers, wich are linked to firewalls.

Comment: I don't understand the last point, how to link provider and firewall, I think it's what I miss

Comment: you should be upgraded (or be able to look at the documentation). :) look for "provider_name" under you firewall config.

Comment: according to http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html there is no option "provider_name", also I've tested it and it didn't work
also the option provider require to create a concrete provider as said above, this is not the right option I think

Answer (score 1):

You can have users authenticate into one firewall and be authenticated on others by configuring the same firewall `context`. Take for example this app/config/security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        filrewall_1:
            ...
            context: my_context
        filrewall_2:
            ...
            context: my_context
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context