# Two differents FOSUser in application

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I face a problem with FOSUserBundle.

In my Symfony2 application, I want to implement two differents User.
I have one entity User, for basic user, and one entity UserPro with more informations.

My problem is that I want to configure my bundle with this two entities:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:    Btp\UserBundle\Entity\User

fos_userpro:
    db_driver:     orm
    firewall_name: pro
    user_class:    Btp\UserProBundle\Entity\UserPro
```

And so, use fos_user and fos_userpro as provider in my security.yml.

I'm no sure it's be possible. I obtain an error :

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "fos_userpro" (in /..../app/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "fos_userpro", found "framework", "security", ...

And when I take a look in FOSUserBundle files, I feel that fos_user is not a configuration variable and is directly written in strings.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your are doing wrong. If userpro have any additional features than ordinary user ,then you can use roles.

Comment: My UserPro has more attributs, like his job. How can I do if I have two differents entity. What do I set in user_class ?

Comment: You can look at [this](https://github.com/netmeansnet/NmnMultiUserBundle#nmnmultiuserbundle) bundle. Haven't tried myself though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation you need to make 4 different entity, user-registration,user-proregistration,users and Groups.For more details you need to look the symfony2 security.

[Click the Link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)

In user-registration,user-proregistration you need an additional field user_id for relating these 2 entity with user.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably checkout this (official) page [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/command_line_tools.md)

Your problem might depends on rôles as previously stated.

For instance you can create an ordinary user like this:

```
php app/console fos:user:create testuser
```

or a user with admin privileges like this:

```
php app/console fos:user:create adminuser --super-admin
```

I recommand you to go htrought the documentation for more options and details about roles.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to redefine FOSUser settings. instead of that, you need to create separate firewall and provider (possibly encoders if you wish). [check this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089698/309268)

`fos_user` is harcoded key in the FOSUser bundle based on what they load settings. you can not just invent your own configuration and expect it to work. think of it as equivalent to `doctrine` or `twig` or `swiftmailer` in your `config.yml`

furthermore `fos_user.firewall_name` is only used in FOSBundle in registration listener to autologin and redirect users after registration if this is enabled.

`fos_user.user_class` is used to create and validate forms, create new users during registration (you can use hooks to add your functionality here) and in simple profile management what is part of FOSUser. in theory it should be possible to use some kind of abstract user entity class in your case, or simply use `User` entity and declare your `Entity\UserPro` extending `Entity\User`.